# When a nonlinear operator has no fixed point?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, nonlinear-analysis

Let B be a normed vector space and $f: B \to B$ be a nonlinear operator. It is well known that the Banach fixed-point theorem or  the Brouwer fixed-point theorem gives conditions which imply that a operator $f$ has a fixed point.
My question is that is there a result on nonexistence of fixed points of a nonlinear operator. That is conditions which ensure that the operator $f$ has no fixed point.

Comment: Nontrivial translations do not admit fixed points, but that is a too a strong condition.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to derive any natural conditions ensuring this. Note that if $F :B \to B$ is arbitrary and $x_0 \in B$, then $G : x \mapsto F(x) - F(x_0) + x_0 $ hast a fixed point. Thus, (even) if $F$ satisfies your condition, $G$ will have to violate it. I don't see any natural condition which will ensure this (except maybe something like $\|F(x)\| \geq \|x\| +1$ or something similar).